# How to add single backslash to a Python list?

Tags: python, list, backslash

I want to add single backslash element to my list. I used `print("\\")` and it printed single backslash; however, when I try to add "\\" to my list, it adds double backslash. How can I solve this problem?

You can see the code below:

```
signs=["+","x","÷","=","/","\\","$","€","£","@","*","!","#",":",";","&","-","(",")","_","'","\"",".",",","?"]

print("Signs:",signs)
```

I use the Python 3.7.3 IDLE as IDE.

From now, thanks for your attention!

Comment: Could you include the code you are actually using?

Comment: Be careful not to confuse the actual string and the python representation of the string. If you print the value in your list this will be a single backslash.

Comment: When you try to add `'\'` it should give you a `SyntaxError`. Note that a single backslash `'\\'` is represented just the same way, so the string *representation* is different from the actual string.

Comment: It's only putting a single backslash in the list. But when you print a list, it shows the representation of the strings in the list, so they're printed with double backslashes.

Comment: And as a side note, have a look at [string.punctuation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#string.punctuation) which gives you '!"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~' and although not necessary, you can pass it to list() in order to convert it to list.

Answer (score 1):

Using a Python REPL

```
>>> ll = [1,2,3]
>>> ll.append('\\')
>>> ll
[1, 2, 3, '\\']
>>> ll[3]
'\\'
>>> print(ll[3])
\
>>>
```

If Python displays a string it needs to Escape the backslash, put if you print the element it shows a single backslash

Answer (score 0):

Your code print the list as a whole:

```
signs=["+","x","÷","=","/","\\","$","€","£","@","*","!","#",":",";","&","-","(",")","_","'","\"",".",",","?"]

print("Signs:",signs)
```

gives:

```
Signs: ['+', 'x', '÷', '=', '/', '\\', '$', '€', '£', '@', '*', '!', '#', ':', ';', '&', '-', '(', ')', '_', "'", '"', '.', ',', '?']
[]
```

Use `*` to print it 'one by one'. `*` is the unpacking operator that turns a list into positional arguments, print(*[a,b,c]) is the same as print(a,b,c).

```
signs=["+","x","÷","=","/","\\","$","€","£","@","*","!","#",":",";","&","-","(",")","_","'","\"",".",",","?"]

print("Signs:",*signs)
```

[image]